# HashMap Sorting based on employeeID

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

You have a Hashmap which stores the information about employee names and their employee ID. Now you want to sort the employees.
Write a program which takes the Hashmap as input and gives back the sorted list of employee ID of employees lD

Employee ID can be alphanumeric. The sorting needs to be done in decreasing order.

**Given**

```
public class solution{
    /*...Complete the function below ...*/

    Static ArrayList<String> orderByEmployeeID(HashMap<string,String> employeeMap) {

    }
}  ⁠ ⁠
```

Comment: This sounds like your homework.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: A `Map` has no guarantee of ordering... You are in for some disappointment here.

Comment: @fge Some `Map` implementations in the Java API do, in fact, offer sorting/navigability, either by key comparator, or by insertion order.

Comment: @hexafraction yes, but this is not the general contract of `Map` in any event. And yes, you have `SortedMap` and `NavigableMap`.

Comment: @JoeyCiechanowicz It's not a homework, this is an interview question and i had just two min to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

we don't do your homework for you here. But maybe these points will help you figure it out. Consider the following:

1) What kind of `HashMap` are you dealing with? "A Hashmap which stores the information about employee names and their employee ID...Employee ID can be alphanumeric". `HashMap`s are key-value pairs. Which field would be the key: The ID or the name? What kind of variable would the ID be if its alphanumeric?

2) Grab that ID and put it into the `List` you'll be returning. You've been given an `ArrayList` as a return type for your method. This type of `List` isn't naturally sorted, so you'll have to sort the IDS yourself within the method body before you add them to the `List`. How would you sort an ID variable that is alphanumeric? There are built-in methods for this. Check out Java's Documentation if you're not sure what methods you can use.

Comment: @Zicron, Thanks for your answer. It's actually an interview question. I was trying to use this for reference. [HashMap](http://java67.blogspot.com/2015/01/how-to-sort-hashmap-in-java-based-on.html)

Comment: Using a `Comparator` to sort the `HashMap` is a good idea in general, but it's sort of pointless for your scenario because you need to return an `ArrayList`. You're better off retrieving the ids from the map and then either add them first and sort the `List` or just sort them and then add them to the `List`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It was realy useful. i added the map key set in the list and used Collections.sort(list).